# Change in the distribution of pressure as a result of angular velocity

Tags: rotational-dynamics, pressure

Let's suppose that there's some compressed liquid inside a rectangular box, and that we're rotating this mass at an angular velocity $\omega$. Let's further suppose that this system is stable, so there's no decrease in the pressure. But then, as we increase the angular velocity from $\omega$ to $2\omega$, can we expect to observe a change in the distribution of pressure?

Answer (score 0):

We can consider the gas as a fluid like water to ease our calculations. For a accelerating $a$ container (having area of cross-section $A$, length $l$) having $p_1, p_2$ pressures at different ends, we can write force equation:$$(p_2-p_1)A=\rho (Al)a$$
$$(p_2-p_1)=\rho (l)a$$

Now our rotating body is another example of accelerated motion. At distance $x$ we can consider a small element $dm=\rho Adx$ of air:

$$Adp=(\rho Adx)a$$
$$a=\omega^2x$$

You can integrate to get your desired result. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a compressible ideal fluid at isothermal conditions.

### Short answer

Using an ideal gas state equation, at isothermal conditions pressure and density are everywhere proportional. During a rigid rotation of the fluid, pressure increases from the axis of rotation towards the outermost parts of the system. Since pressure increases, density increases as well. To satisfy mass conservation in the closed system, compared to the system at rest, during the rotation the density of the fluid has lower value on the axis and higher values in the outermost regions.

### Detailed answer

If the fluid has no relative motion w.r.t. the box, all its fluid particles are performing a circular trajectory.

Taking the convective differential form of the momentum equation,

$\rho\mathbf{a} = \rho \mathbf{g} + \nabla \cdot \mathbb{T} $,

being $\mathbb{T}$ the stress tensor that in general can be written for a Newtonian fluid as $\mathbb{T} = - P \mathbb{I} + 2 \mu \mathbb{D} + \lambda (\nabla  \cdot \mathbf{u}) \mathbb{I}$, while for rigid rotation motion reduces as $ \mathbb{T} = -P \mathbb{I}$, since no viscous stress exists in a rigid rotation motion. Thus the divergence of the stress tensor becomes $\nabla \cdot \mathbb{T}^{rigid} = \nabla \cdot (-P \mathbb{I}) = - \nabla P$. For negligible volume forces $\mathbf{g} \simeq \mathbf{0}$, we can write the equations of motion as

$\rho \mathbf{a} = - \nabla P$.

This vector equation can be projected on a Frenet basis on the trajectory of every particle:

- tangent direction $\rho a_t = - \mathbf{\hat{t}} \cdot \nabla P$,
- normal direction $\rho a_n = - \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla P$,
- binormal direction $\rho a_b = - \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \nabla P$,

being

- $a_t = r \dot\Omega$ the tangential acceleration of the fluid particle, with $r$ the radius of the circular particle trajectory around the axis of rotation and $\Omega$ the angular velocity of the system; if we suppose constant angular velocity $\dot \Omega = 0$;
- $a_n = r \Omega^2$ the centripetal acceleration, with the positive direction pointing towards the inside of the circular trajectory;
- $a_b = 0$ the acceleration in the bi-normal direction.

Thus, putting everything together with the assumption of the constant angular velocity we get:

- $\mathbf{\hat{t}} \cdot \nabla P = 0$
- $\mathbf{\hat{b}} \cdot \nabla P = 0$ and thus $P = P(r)$ only
- $\rho r \Omega^2 = P'(r)$

Using ideal gas state equation at constant $T = \overline{T}$, $P = \rho R \overline{T}$, we get 1 variable differential equation for P(r), namely

$\dfrac{P(r)}{R \overline{T}} r\Omega^2 = -P'(r)$,

that can be integrated as

$\dfrac{dP}{P} = \dfrac{r \Omega^2}{R \overline{T}} dr$

to get

$\ln \dfrac{P(r)}{P_0} = \dfrac{\Omega^2}{2 R \overline{T}} \left( r^2 - r_0^2 \right) $$\quad \rightarrow \quad$ $P(r; \Omega) = P_0 e^{ \frac{\Omega^2}{2 R \overline{T}} \left( r^2 - r_0^2 \right)}$

Taking the first integration extreme to be on the rotation axis, $r_0 = 0$, pressure and density fields reads

$P(r; \Omega) = \dfrac{P_0}{R\overline{T}} e^{ \frac{\Omega^2}{2 R \overline{T}} r^2 }$
$\rho(r; \Omega) = \dfrac{P(r)}{R \overline{T}} = \dfrac{P_0}{R\overline{T}} e^{ \frac{\Omega^2}{2 R \overline{T}} r^2}$,

being $P_0$ the integration constant equal to the pressure at the points on the axis of rotation.

In order to find the value of the integration constant $P_0$, you need to prescribe the mass conservation, i.e. the integral of the density in the box at rest equals the integral of the density during rotation, i.e.

$M = \displaystyle\int_V \rho(r;\Omega) dV = \int_V \dfrac{P_0}{R\overline{T}} e^{ \frac{\Omega^2}{2 R \overline{T}} r^2}  dV$.

Using a cylindrical box, instead of a rectangular one, the integral reads

$I(\Omega) = \displaystyle \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{h=0}^{H} \int_{r=0}^{R^{max}} e^{ \frac{\Omega^2}{2 R \overline{T}} r^2 }  r dr dh d\theta = 
2\pi H \dfrac{1}{2}\frac{2 R \overline{T}}{\Omega^2} \int_{r=0}^{R^{max}} e^{ \frac{\Omega^2}{2 R \overline{T}} r^2 }  d\left( \frac{\Omega^2}{2 R \overline{T}} r^2 \right) =
 2\pi H \frac{R \overline{T}}{\Omega^2} \left[ e^{ \frac{\Omega^2}{2 R \overline{T}} {R^{max}}^2 } - 1 \right]
$,

so that the pressure on the axis reads

$P_0 (\Omega) = M R \overline{T} \dfrac{1}{I(\Omega)}$.

*(Hope I performed the computation right; anyway that's the way you need to proceed to find the pressure on the axis of rotation and the pressure and density field of a compressible gas at isothermal conditions performing rigid rotation in a closed box)*